# SmartExtensionUtils on sony smartwatch SDK

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I have added the SmartExtensionUtils and SmartExtensionAPI to my project as project libraries but the SmartExtensionUtils is FULL of errors, is there something that has to be linked to this file as well? I asked a previous question on here and it resolved that issue and brought me to this one now, I appreciate your help

Comment: If the previous answer given on the other question resolved an issue, you should upvote/accept it. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). And add more detail to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding the SmartExtensionAPI in SmartExtensionUtils project in Properties->Java Build Path->Projects